# How to free a C struct?

Tags: c, objective-c, struct, malloc

Given a struct, e.g.

```
typedef struct
{
  int value;
} TestStruct;
```

Why does the following code (in the context of an Objective-C class running on the IPhone) throw a "non-aligned pointer being freed" exception?

```
TestStruct ts = {33};
free(&ts);
```

N.B. My uber goal is to use a C library with many vector-math functions, hence the need to find out some viable way to mix C and Objective-C

Comment: Objective-C is simply a strict superset of C, so you can completely intermix them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to free a stack or static variable. You need to have malloc()'d something for it to be able to be free()'d.

Try this instead:

```
TestStruct *ts = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
ts->value = 33;
free(ts);
```

For those more familiar with object-oriented languages, you might find it helpful to create a constructor:

```
TestStruct *newTestStruct(int value)
{
    TestStruct *ret = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
    ret->value = value;
    return ret;
}
```

This enables you to allocate a struct and set the values in one step. Just remember that this value should be freed once it's no longer useful:

```
TestStruct *x = newTestStruct(3);
free(x);
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks! But then: any mean to allocate and populate at the same time?

Comment: No direct way, but you can create your own constructor if you want. I edited the post to explain how to do that.

Comment: Thank you to the people that voted this answer up after the edit. I just got into the 10k club! :-D

Comment: I does not understand what happen if when we got a lot of votes from reader of the question with answer? I want to say meaning 10K club?

Answer (score 7):

Because you are trying to free something that was allocated on the stack. The function free() can only be called on memory that was allocated with malloc().

Comment: True. But this person doesn't seem to have a good grasp of heap v. stack, so let's not confuse him with the subtleties of various kinds of static allocation :).

Comment: Exactly! (from the Java person in question :-)